# Настройка роутинга в CodeIgniter

Tags: framework, php, codeigniter

Всем доброго времени суток...  У меня такой вопрос, как осуществить следующее:
есть ссылка вида `http://site.ru/news?id=[news-id]` и нужно переделать так, чтобы ссылка работала по адресу `http://site.ru/[news-id]` Отображение через `http://site.ru/news?id=[news-id]` уже сделано. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте в файле routes.php дописать следующее:

```
$route['(:num)']  = 'news?id=$1';
```

имеется ввиду `$1` - это `[news-id]`

А где поставлена ссылка на

```
news?id=[news-id]
```

Заменить на

```
[news-id]
```

Если так не работает, может в файле .htaccess в корне сайта должны быть такие строки?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|img|styles|demo|files|js|recommend|products|partner)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: В корне сайта в .htaccess есть такие строки

    RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)  
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

Comment: $config['index_page'] = 'index.php';

Comment: Убрал строчку $config['index_page'] = 'index.php'; - не работает(

Comment: В файле 
application/config/autoload.php
загружен хелпер? - url
$autoload['helper'] = array('url');

Comment: http://site.ru/[news-id] именно так нужно что бы выглядела ссылка или типа 

http://site.ru/7

Comment: да, как в последнем варианте.. но не обязательно цифры (буквы, цифры и _) http://site.ru/ilya http://site.ru/lol_12_m Добавте меня в скайпе stomati1, там поговорим, но буду чуть позже